# Onebox Google+ posts in chat?

Tags: feature-request, onebox, google-plus

Please support oneboxing of Google+ posts in chat, like it is done for Twitter posts.

**Why it would be useful**

A naked link does not give users any hint of what the post might be about. Seeing the post's title, the posts author and the first few sentences may be helpful to users to deduce the context of the link (connecting it to others ongoing discussions in the channel) and to decide whether to follow the link or not.

Comment: If you request a feature, at least give arguments *why* it should be implemented.

Comment: @Rob ... for the same reason we have preview for youtube / twitter posts? I don't know whether it's helpful to educate people on the benefits of previews in chats, especially given that previews are already implemented for the mentioned sites (and others). I think I would miss several advantages of previews that others (especially the SO authors themselfs) could explain better.

Comment: @Rob i tried to describe the purpose of a preview in my question. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Looks better now. I'm not using Google Plus, so I can't judge any more.

Comment: See also http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1696/is-oneboxing-for-google-posts-coming-to-the-chat

Answer (score 4):

I'm not explicitly declining this, since I don't have a real problem with it, but to be honest my personal view of this is a strong and heartfelt "meh". We don't do Facebook either, after all.

This is really one of those "If a dev is bored and feels like implementing it" things, in particular since there's [about a billion things you have to look at](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities#resource) for G+ updates.

Comment: But tweets are OneBoxed... I guess the meh-factor was less on that one?

Comment: A tweet is a *perfect* oneboxing candidate, because the onebox actually makes it unnecessary to follow the link; you get the full content right there. But yes, the meh-factor is also less on that one.

Comment: Google+ posts can have the same use as a Twitter post. They can give information in one fell swoop. For example: https://plus.google.com/105339876636828542152/posts/7sLhgx2ohm2